# highlight newly inserted row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I setup my gridview to handle the edit,delete, and insert operations correctly. My grid also supports paging and sorting. My question is how to highlight and go to the newly inserted row in my grid?

Comment: Can you specify what property distinguishes "newly inserted" from older inserted ?

Answer (score 0):

If the newly inserted row is always going to be the last row of your grid (or the first, for instance), then you could just get the grid to select either the first or the last row after an insert is performed.

My advice (if this method is appropriate) would be to execute your selection code right after you've performed the rebind after the insert. If you can't do that,for any reason,then when the new row is inserted, store a value in the Session object to indicate that a new row has been added (eg. `Session("RowAdded") = True`) and check for it on your grid's data binding events.

HTH,

Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Property as `shouldHighlight`, which will define, particular row to highlight.

whichever record is added or updated, set the flag as true, and for other records, set as false.

in RowDataBound Event, 
Check if particular row has the flag as true, apply CSS or Background color to the row.

```
 protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Record objR = (Record)e.Row.DataItem;
                if (objR.shouldHighLight)
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                }
            }
        }
```

in my example `Record` is a Class
as

```
 public class Record {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool shouldHighLight { get; set; }
    }
```

let me know your thoughts.